# How to get all non empty selects and text inputs in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

How to get all non empty selects and text inputs in JQuery?

I need to find all non empty selects and text inputs and `.show()` their parents.

I think I don't have to use a loop for this, selector should be enough.

I tried:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('input[value!=""]').parent('class').show();
});
```

But this doesn't do anything

Comment: Can you create a working example of your problem please? Or maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: The selector works on this page here, by removing the `'class'` from the parent call.

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through them using `each()` :

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('select').each(function(){
         if ( !$(this).val() )
              $(this).closest('.class').show();
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [jquery filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to limit the selection according to your need like,

```
$('document').ready(function(){    
    $('input[type="text"], select').filter(function () {
        return !!$(this).val();
    }).parent('.class').show();
});
```

regards